Is there a downside to using $index as track in a for loop
Given the following example within a PrimeNG Table, there should be a skeleton visible while loading data:
  <ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody">
    <tr>
      @for (i of [].constructor(3); track $index) {
        <td>
          <p-skeleton />
        </td>
      }
    </tr>
  </ng-template>

In this example, the variable $index is used as a track. Does this have a disadvantage? Could this not be used by all for loops?
Alternatively, you could also make a member field in the class:
class TableComponent {
  protected readonly columnCount = Array.from({length: 3}).map((,index) => index);
}

Would this approach be different from using the $index variable?

I don't understand your last question "Would this approach be different from using the $index variable?". Creating an array is something completely different than iterating over an array in the template.

So in the first example the Array is constructed inline within the template ([].constructor(3)) and in the other example as class field member, which could be iterated like @for (i of columnCount; track i) {. Does it make any difference? e.g. performance wise?

AFAIK it does not make any significant difference. In both cases, the array will just be constructed once while initializing the component.

$index should only be used for static collections, see the docs. So no, it is not suitable as a default for all loops. If the collection changes at runtime, using $index can lead to the DOM not reacting to the changes.
In your case however it's totally fine to use $index, as the collection never changes.
